# I try to connect an external DB (mySql 5.7) to popolate my entity in Liferay 7.0. But there si an exception

Tags: java, mysql, liferay-7

My `ext-spring.xml` is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<bean class="com.liferay.portal.dao.jdbc.spring.DataSourceFactoryBean" id="liferayDataSourceFactory">
        <property name="propertyPrefix" value="jdbc.ext." />
</bean>
```

In `service.xml` I use `data-source=extDataSource`

In my portal-ext-properties I use with the right configuration:

```
jdbc.ext.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.ext.password=
jdbc.ext.url=jdbc:
jdbc.ext.username=
```

But Liferay has this Exception :

```
is invalid; 
nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; 
lineNumber: 3; 
columnNumber: 102; 
cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'bean'
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `ext-spring.xml` file is invalid. It is hard to say what exactly is causing this without the full XML file and the full stacktrace.